# Using a resw file in a Universal App

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm following the instructions at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx on how to add a resources file, but I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't work.

I created a new Universal app, checking that the Default language is set to en-US in both Package.appxmanifest files.

I created a Resources.resw file, in Strings/en-US. This file has three values:

```
Greeting.Text = Hello
Greeting.Width = 20
Farewell = Goodbye
```

Then, in MainPage.xaml, I've got the following:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="Greeting" Text="" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I run the app, nothing appears - the text box has no content. The instructions in the MS quickstart don't say it, but does some sort of additional association have to be done, such as referencing the Resources.resw file in the App.xaml?

Comment: Are you sure you have this under the `Strings` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant `TextBlock` (not `TextBox`) has no content when you run the app.

A couple of things to check:

- Does it help if you delete `Greeting.Width` or set it to a larger value (maybe `TextBlock`) is to narrow to show anything)?
- Could the text be hidden behind the performance counters in the top left corner of the app? Try adding `Margin="100"` to your `TextBlock` just to be sure.
- Do you have `BuildAction` for `Resources.resw` set to `PRIResource`?
- You don't have any other code which could affect the content of your `TextBlock`?

If this doesn't help, can you put your sample somewhere for download? This would make it easier to troubleshoot.